# PHP Mailer - attachment

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am trying to send a image as an attachment on the form.
But after hit submit, I see `"Sorry the server was unable to upload the files...".`

If anyone knows the reason, please let me know.
Thank you in advance.

```
<?php
require("class.phpmailer.php");

$name = "the Submitter";
$email_subject = "photo Attachment";
$Email_msg ="A visitor submitted the following :\n";
$Email_to = "someone1@someone.com"; 
$email_from = "someone2@someone.net";
$dir = "uploads/$filename";
chmod("uploads",0777);
$attachments = array();

checkType();

function checkType() {
  while(list($key,$value) = $_FILES[photo][type]){
    strtolower($value);
    if($value != "image/jpeg" AND $value != "image/pjpeg" AND $value != "") {
      exit('Sorry , current format is <b>'.($value).'</b> ,only Jpeg or jpg are allowed.') ;
    }
  }
  checkSize();
}


function checkSize(){
  while(list($key,$value) = ($_FILES[photo][size]))
  {
    $maxSize = 5000000;
    if(!empty($value)){
      if ($value > $maxSize) {
        echo"Sorry this is a very big file .. max file size is $maxSize Bytes = 5 MB";
        exit();
      }
      else {
        $result = "File size is ok !<br>";
      }
    }
  }
  uploadFile();
}


function uploadFile() {
  global $attachments;
  while(list($key,$value) = ($_FILES[photo][name]))
  {

  if(!empty($value))
  {
    $filename = $value;
    $dir = "uploads/$filename";
    chmod("uploads",0777);
    $success = copy($_FILES[photo][tmp_name][$key], $dir);
  }

}

if ($success) {
  echo " Files Uploaded Successfully<BR>";
  SendIt();

}else {
  exit("Sorry the server was unable to upload the files...");
}

}



function SendIt() {

  global $attachments,$name,$Email_to,$Email_msg,$email_subject,$email_from;

  $mail = new PHPMailer();
  $mail->IsSMTP();
  $mail->Host = "localhost"; 
  $mail->SMTPAuth = false; 
  $mail->From = $email_from;
  $mail->FromName = $name;
  $mail->AddAddress($Email_to);
  $mail->AddReplyTo($email_from);
  $mail->WordWrap = 50;

  foreach($attachments as $key => $value) { 
    $mail->AddAttachment("uploads"."/".$value);
  }
  $mail->Body = $Email_msg."Name : ".$name."\n";

  $mail->IsHTML(false);
  $mail->Subject = $email_subject;
  if(!$mail->Send())
  {
    echo "Message was not sent <p>";
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    exit;
  }

  echo "Message has been sent";

  foreach($attachments as $key => $value) {
    unlink("uploads"."/".$value);
  }

}

?>
```

Comment: Try using [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) to upload files instead of `copy()`

Comment: Plus this `$success = copy($_FILES[photo][tmp_name]` missing quotes inside and other areas too. That's being treated as [constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php).

Comment: please, first remove all email-related stuff from your code and make sure file upload works. Only after that start adding email capabilities. The problem has nothing to do with email.

Comment: Thank you now it says different message.

Comment: Are you going to tell us what it is, or do we have to guess?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answering my question. Finally, it worked.
Below is the one which worked.

```
<?php
require("PATH/PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php");


$name = "the Submitter";
$email_subject = "photo Attachment";
$Email_msg ="A visitor submitted the following :\n";
$Email_to = "someone1@someone.com"; 
$email_from = "someone2@someone.net";
$dir = "uploads/$filename";
chmod("uploads",0777);
chmod("PATH/uploads",0777);
$attachments = array();

checkType();


function checkType() {
strtolower($_FILES[photo][type]);
if($value != "image/jpeg" AND $value != "image/pjpeg" AND $value != "") {
exit('Sorry , current format is <b>'.($value).'</b> ,only Jpeg or jpg are allowed.') ;

}

checkSize();

}



function checkSize(){

$value = $_FILES[photo][size];
$maxSize = 5000000;
if(!empty($value)){
if ($value > $maxSize) {
echo"Sorry this is a very big file .. max file size is $maxSize Bytes = 5 MB";
exit();
}
else {
$result = "File size is ok !<br>";

}

}


uploadFile();

}




function uploadFile() {
global $attachments;

$value = $_FILES[photo][name];

if(!empty($value))
{
$filename = $value;
$dir = "PATH/uploads/$filename";
$success = move_uploaded_file($_FILES[photo][tmp_name], $dir);
   if($success){
$attachments = $value;
   }
}


if ($success) {
echo " Files Uploaded Successfully<BR>";
SendIt();



}else {
exit("Sorry the server was unable to upload the files...");
}

}



function SendIt() {

global $attachments,$name,$Email_to,$Email_msg,$email_subject,$email_from;

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();//
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls"; 
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->Username = "xxx@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "xxx";
$mail->From = $email_from;
$mail->FromName = $name;
$mail->AddAddress($Email_to);
$mail->AddReplyTo($email_from);
$mail->WordWrap = 50;

foreach($attachments as $key => $value) { 
$mail->AddAttachment("PATH/uploads"."/".$value);
}
$mail->Body = $Email_msg."Name : ".$name."\n";

$mail->IsHTML(false);
$mail->Subject = $email_subject;
if(!$mail->Send())
{
echo "Message was not sent <p>";
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
exit;
}

echo "Message has been sent";

foreach($attachments as $key => $value) {
unlink("PATH/uploads"."/".$value);
}

}

?>
```